# Subtracting dynamic value from date stored in another dynamic variable

Tags: php, string, date, datetime

I need to subtract a number of days from a date which is stored in a dynamic variable '$workdate' .

The number of days to be subtracted from the date is also generating dynamically.

```
$workdate=date('d/m/y', strtotime($wdate)); //$wdate is a date selected from date picker and passed from previous page.
```

I have a variable named '$deduc' whose value is dynamically generating. suppose $deduc=2 now I need to do:

```
$workdate-$deduc=?

$workdate=date('d/m/y', strtotime($wdate));

while($some_value=0)
{
  $deduc=$deduc+1;
  $some_value--;

}
```

now I need to subtract $deduc no. of days from $workdate. Please do help.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object with [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) your date, e.g.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", $workdate);
echo $date->modify("- $deduc days")->format('Y-m-d');
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/VUTFM)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and especially at the [DateTime::sub()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) method.

Comment: i ve checked those. but none of them have a dynamic value. my date stored in a variable is dynamically generated as a result of some other calculations.

Comment: @DewDrop I don't get why that should be a problem. You can use your dynamically generated date with the DateTime class without any problems. Have you already tried it? If yes, please post your tries.